# Add php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to get the Wordpress page title into a javascript code, but everything what I have tried so far didn't work. It's a Wordpress plugin. I'd like to fire an event when someone scrolls the page. The whole plugin works, but I want to add the page title to the event script which should look like this in order to see in Analytics what pages they have scrolled

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'scroll', 'the page title', 'scrolled']);
```

I have tried with `<php? the_title() ?>`, `get_the_title()` varieties, but I didn't manage.

This plugin runs outside the loop so I need to get the title somehow. Anyone out there with ideas?

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Fix Bounce Rate
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fix-bounce-rate
Description: Fix Bounce Rate
Author: Bounce rate fixer
Version: 0.1
*/

function plugin_options() { ?>
<?php
if($_POST['plugin_show'] == 'go') {
$pluginscript = $_POST['plugin_script'];
update_option('plugin_script', $pluginscript);
?>
<div class="notif"> <span>
<?php _e('Options saved' ); ?>
</span> </div>
<?php
} else {
$pluginscript = get_option('plugin_script');
}
?>
<form class="script-form" name="plugin_form" method="post" action="<?php echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
<fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="plugin_show" value="go">
<textarea id="textarea" rows="25" name="plugin_script">
<?php  
if($pluginscript){echo stripslashes($pluginscript);}
else { ?>
<script>
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
(function (tos) {
window.total_time = 0;
window.setInterval(function () {
total_time += 10;
tos = (function (t) {
return t[0] == 50 ? (parseInt(t[1]) + 1) + ':00' : (t[1] || '0') + ':' + (parseInt(t[0]) + 10);
})(tos.split(':').reverse());
setTimeout(function() {
window.onscroll = function() {
window.onscroll = null;
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'scroll', 'scrolled']);
}
}, 2000);
if (window.total_time <= 1800) {
window.pageTracker ? pageTracker._trackEvent('Time', 'Log', tos) : _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Time', 'Log', tos]);
}
}, 10000);
})('00');
</script>
<?php } ?>
</textarea>
<br />
<button type="submit">Save</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
<?php
}

function plugin_settings() {
add_options_page('plugin', 'Fix Bouncerate', 'manage_options', 'plugin', 'plugin_options');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'plugin_settings');

$pluginscript = get_option('plugin_script');

function pluginplace() {
$pluginscript = get_option('plugin_script');
echo stripslashes($pluginscript);
}
add_action('wp_footer','pluginplace');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you address your Script-File from your template, you could add the title as a GET-Parameter to the scripts URL. You should be able to read the title in that file.
Then in your script file just read that $_GET Variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.php?title=MY_PAGE_TITLE"></script>
```

Or just set a global JS-Variable in your head section that you fill with a PHP-Value and reference that variable in your script file. Be sure to set the variable before the script is executed!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myTitle = '<?php echo $var_with_title; ?>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use javascript native document.title? Is your title dynamic generated?

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'scroll', document.title, 'scrolled']);
```

like this

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'scroll', <?php echo("'".the_title()."'"); ?>, 'scrolled']);
```

your code

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Fix Bounce Rate
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fix-bounce-rate
Description: Fix Bounce Rate
Author: Bounce rate fixer
Version: 0.1
*/

function plugin_options() { ?>
<?php
if($_POST['plugin_show'] == 'go') {
$pluginscript = $_POST['plugin_script'];
update_option('plugin_script', $pluginscript);
?>
<div class="notif"> <span>
<?php _e('Options saved' ); ?>
</span> </div>
<?php
} else {
$pluginscript = get_option('plugin_script');
}
?>
<form class="script-form" name="plugin_form" method="post" action="<?php echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
<fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="plugin_show" value="go">
<textarea id="textarea" rows="25" name="plugin_script">
<?php  
if($pluginscript){echo stripslashes($pluginscript);}
else { ?>
<script>
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
(function (tos) {
window.total_time = 0;
window.setInterval(function () {
total_time += 10;
tos = (function (t) {
return t[0] == 50 ? (parseInt(t[1]) + 1) + ':00' : (t[1] || '0') + ':' + (parseInt(t[0]) + 10);
})(tos.split(':').reverse());
setTimeout(function() {
window.onscroll = function() {
window.onscroll = null;
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'scroll', <?php echo("'".the_title()."'"); ?>, 'scrolled']);
}
}, 2000);
if (window.total_time <= 1800) {
window.pageTracker ? pageTracker._trackEvent('Time', 'Log', tos) : _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Time', 'Log', tos]);
}
}, 10000);
})('00');
</script>
<?php } ?>
</textarea>
<br />
<button type="submit">Save</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
<?php
}

function plugin_settings() {
add_options_page('plugin', 'Reduce Bounce Rate', 'manage_options', 'plugin', 'plugin_options');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'plugin_settings');

$pluginscript = get_option('plugin_script');

function pluginplace() {
$pluginscript = get_option('plugin_script');
echo stripslashes($pluginscript);
}
add_action('wp_footer','pluginplace');
?>
```

Comment: The title is dynamicly generated with `<?php the_title(); ?>`. When I use the line above document.title is just printed, not the page title.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I tried first but the output is
`_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'scroll', '<?php the_title(); ?>', 'scrolled']);` It just prints whatever code is there.

Comment: I just tried to add the script part (including the the_title()) directly to the footer and then the page title showed up. So, the big question is why is it not showing up when I do it via the plugin...?

Comment: Still prints the code
`_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'scroll', <?php echo("'".the_title()."'"); ?>, 'scrolled']);`

In the database it is stored as
`_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'scroll\', <?php echo(\"\'\".the_title().\"\'\"); ?>, \'scrolled\']);`

Comment: use phpmyadmin remove those slashes

Comment: Still no luck. Whether I remove the backslashes or not it still prints the code. Wish I know why.